# Deleting file geodatabase using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, arcgis-pro

I am trying to delete a geodatabase using arcpy but I don't know how to do it. I have tried with 'Delete_management' but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
path = D:\ArcGIS_Pro_Projects\KML files\geodatabase_name.gdb
arcpy.Delete_management(path)
```

Comment: *I have tried with 'Delete_management' but it doesn't work* <-- Show us what you tried and the result that was returned or the error that was raised.

Answer (score 4):

the path variable should be a string. put it in quotes like this:

```
path = 'D:\\ArcGIS_Pro_Projects\\KML files\\geodatabase_name.gdb'
arcpy.Delete_management(path)
```

Comment: It also either needs to have all forward slashes, or you can put an r in front. Such as path = r 'D:\ArcGIS_Pro_Projects\KML files\geodatabase_name.gdb'

Comment: It kind of works now. It does delete the geodatabase from my folder, but it doesn't remove it from the ArcGIS Pro catalog. It still appears on the Databases drop down menu (which doesn't make much sense since it doesn't exist anymore).

Comment: That is a pointer to the database. The delete command does not tell ArcGIS Pro project to remove the reference.

Comment: Refresh the catalog.  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/refreshcatalog.htm